# SQL 2000 and SQL 2008 Express side by side?

Tags: sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-express

This question has been asked in regards to 2005, but did not see anything with 2000.  We have a new application that needs to run on 2005 or better but everything else we have is geared towards 2000.  We could upgrade, but that is not within budget at this time.

We were thinking we could run SQL Server 2008 Express on the same server as 2000 for the period of time it takes before we upgrade.

Anyone do this?
Have any issue?
Ok to proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On our development server we have lots of versions installed eg: 2000, 2005 Express, 2005 standard, 2008 express we haven't had any major problems.

You will need to install them as named instances when you go through the installation procedure, eg:

MyServer\SQL2000
MyServer\SQL2005Express
MyServer\SQL2005
etc

I wouldn't advise running this many versions or instances on a production box but 2 instances until you upgrade your other applications to 2005 should be no problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have a server that runs both sql2000 and 2005 and i have had not problems whatsoever - sql2005 is running a seperate instance.

I see no problems with proceeding.  The only issue i've had is 2005 express does not have DTS/SSIS so getting data in is cumbersome, but that has nothing to do with running both :-)

Comment: OP asked about SQL 2008 Express, not 2005.